# forward declaration in c++

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I want to forward declare:

```
namespace boost {
    namespace property_tree {
        template<typename Key, typename Data, typename KeyCompare = std::less<Key> >
        class basic_ptree;
        typedef basic_ptree< std::string, std::string > ptree;
    }
}
```

but my g++ cribs about redefinition due to default template argument. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>` not an option?

Answer (score 5):

To forward-declare the property_tree, you should include the

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree_fwd.hpp>
```

header, instead of declaring one yourself.

Comment: The point about a forward declaration is that you do not want to include the header.

Comment: @Job: Wrong. The point about [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) is *not giving the complete definition of the whole structure*, to allow forward reference.

Comment: ... when a header is called `..._fwd.hpp`

Comment: @KennyTM: Sure, that's what I meant. I agree I didn't make it very clear:-) Also, I didn't notice the `_fwd.hpp`. Does Boost make special headers for forward declarations?

Comment: @Job: Yes. Because the how the stuffs are defined are often unspecified, the only safe way is to include the `_fwd` header.

Comment: Kenny, Thanks for your reply. But thats not what I wanted. I have a header file which has a reference to ptree but I didn't want to include boost header files in this file as this would make all other code which includes this header will have to include boost. I wanted to forward declare the boost dependencies and remove the boost inclusion.

Anyway I've found out a way.